# How do I add the text links to the drop down navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created the three layer button for mobile devices for my website, but when I click on it, nothing happens. I'm not sure how to add the feature so when you click on it, the navigation links like home etc on full screen go on the drop down list on the button. Below is the code I have written so far.

```css
nav .menu-holder {
  width: calc(90px + 20px);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

nav .menu-holder .menu-icon {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav .menu-holder .menu-icon span {
  max-width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

nav .menu-holder .menu-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}

nav .menu-holder .menu-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
}

nav .menu-holder .menu-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  nav .menu-holder {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 col-lg-3">
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/60/60" class="logo-holder" alt="Site Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-10 col-lg-9">
        <div class="menu-holder">
          <div class="menu-icon">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="cssmenu">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="hasDropdown">
            <a href="#">Dropdown Link</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am not sure what code I need to write for the menus to pop after you clicked the button on mobile view. Here is a screenshot of the mobile version button

https://gyazo.com/03a1ef176ad7f1aec6be029f47d345b0

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any CSS written for it?

Comment: if its bootstrap than you have to use **<a href="#" class="data-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Dropdown Link</a>** just like that

Comment: I have added the CSS. I am still new to this so sorry if its wrong. It is not bootstrap.

Comment: If it's not bootstrap then what is it?

Comment: Sorry, it is bootstrap. I'm confused on where I add that command you said for bootstrap to make it work?

Comment: This Bootstrap example page should have all the code you need: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/starter-template/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CSS and JavaScript. HTML does not have the ability to change DOM elements. W3 has a How To [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp).

Since you say you are using Bootstrap they have excellent documentation on how their navbars work. You can find the relevant section [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).

It looks like your code is mainly missing the relevant bootstrap classes. Once you add those you should be good.

HTML for content, CSS for styling, JavaScript for functionality. Although CSS and JavaScript frameworks blur the lines somewhat now.

Comment: jQuery IS Javascript. Also he said he uses Bootstrap, so the Javascript is already there

Comment: Hmm, I don't know much about Javascript. Is the code a lot to make it work on Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just confused. I have done the HTML and CSS part, just confused on the code to make it work. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @Robert Hubbard Thanks for your updated comment. I am struggling on completing this, is there anybody that I can send the files to, then you can check yourself, because I think I have made a complete hash out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fiddle for you
You can use click bind etc and improve but it'll get you started
https://jsfiddle.net/Steven_Whitby/rg84t62f/

Html

```
    <div class="menu-bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item" onMouseOver="$('.drop-menu').show()" onMouseOut="$('.drop-menu').hide()" style="list-style: none;cursor: default;">
            Dropdown Link
            <ul class="drop-menu">
                <li class="drop-item"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li class="drop-item"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li class="drop-item"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                <li class="drop-item"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                <li class="drop-item"><a href="#">Five</a></li>
                <li class="drop-item"><a href="#">Six</a></li>
                <li class="drop-item"><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-bar {
    background-color: #57578b;
    height: 25px;
}
.menu-item {
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    /* font-size: 1.2em; */
    text-decoration: none!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
.drop-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: rgb(87, 87, 138);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.drop-item {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.drop-item:hover {
    background-color: rgb(181, 178, 178);
    color: black;
}
```